# How often does a Gargantuan with the Bruiser rune stun?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The level 56 Witch Doctor rune for Gargantuan called "Bruiser" has the following effect:

> Bruiser
>   The Gargantuan gains the ability to periodically slam enemies, dealing 100% of your weapon damage as Physical and stunning them for 3 seconds.

Is there any indication as to how often "periodically" is?  Are there abilities or items that can change the frequency of this effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Went ahead and tested this.

Method: Took the Gargantuan outside of New Tristram and watched/timed him as he punched zombies. Removed and Reequipped items to test INT, Weapon Damage, and Attack Speed gains and timed their effect on the stun.

**Findings:**

- Against a single target the Gargantuan stunned the enemy around every
  10 seconds. Against a group he appears to do the same.
- The stun appeared to last around 3.5 seconds. Probably due to lag and attack animations.
- INT, Weapon Damage, and Attack Speed increases did not appear to
  increase how often the Gargantuan would stun or the duration of the stun.